# Shell.Exec in FAKE

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I found this function `Exec` here http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-processhelper-shell.html.

```
Target "UpdateTools" (fun _ ->
   Exec "cmd"
)
```

But I keep getting this error, when I try to run it: "The value or constructor 'Exec' is not defined".

I'm new to FAKE and have not used F#, so forgive me if this should be obvious.

Can someone tell me why this api is not accessible like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation is documenting class Shell. That means, you need to call it like:

```
Target "UpdateTools" (fun _ ->
   ignore(Shell.Exec "cmd")
)
```

or, if you need to work with the error code further:

```
Target "UpdateTools" (fun _ ->
    let errorCode = Shell.Exec "cmd"
    //do something with the error code
    ()
)
```

Hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: Could you please add an example, of how to call the Exec method with multiple parameters?

Comment: `let result = Shell.Exec("batch.bat", "param1 param2 " + variableAsParam3)
    if result <> 0 then failwithf "%s exited with error %d" "batch.bat" result)`